# Forget history position

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, command-history

Currently I using Bash with Cygwin. With Bash, I can enter these commands:

```
$ date
Thu, Apr 23, 2020  7:51:43 PM

$ echo Sunday
Sunday
```

Then if I press Up twice, I get this, as expected:

```
$ date
```

If I want to cancel, I can press down twice, or Ctrl + C. After I have canceled,
if I press Up again, it gives me the most recent result, as expected:

```
$ echo Sunday
```

Now contrast with Command Prompt. I can enter these commands:

```
C:\> where calc
C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe

C:\> where notepad
C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
```

Then if I press Up twice, I get this, as expected:

```
C:\> where calc
```

but if I want to cancel, I cant press down twice. It only lets you press down
once, so that the most recent command displays:

```
C:\> where notepad
```

as a workaround, you can press Esc. But then if you press Up, you dont get the
most recent result anymore. Because it didnt let you scroll all the way down,
you get this:

```
C:\> where calc
```

Seems same problem with Ctrl + C too. I dont want the shell trying to be smart,
and remembering the position in the history. Does Windows have some option to
change this behavior, with registry or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of PowerShell do not have this issue, so I switched shells.

Answer (score 0):

The Command Prompt might feel little stiff when comming back from Unix like terminal or its port (like Cygwin or git bash etc.).

I don't beleive there is anything you can do about it, except of trying to learn how it works and adapt it's different workflow.

Whant might help you out though is to press F7 to view your history in pop-up window.

Also you can try to use Page Up and Page Down on keyboard to get yourself to the first or last command in the history respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Command Prompt has a long history. Most of its features are the same
as they were in [DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS),
which dates to four decades ago (!).

Microsoft gave up on developing the Command Prompt any further, and has the intention
of replacing it in the future with the new
[Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal).
You could test this new product, as its history handling is bound to be better.

Another possibility is to use an add-on to the Command Prompt that adds Linux-like
history handling, the [Clink project](http://mridgers.github.io/clink/):

> Clink combines the native Windows shell `cmd.exe` with the powerful command line editing features of the GNU Readline library, which provides rich completion, history, and line-editing capabilities.

Another well-known alternative to the Command Prompt, is
[ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/):

> ConEmu-Maximus5 aims to be handy, comprehensive, fast and reliable terminal window where you may host any console application developed either for WinAPI (cmd, powershell, far) or Unix PTY (cygwin, msys, wsl bash).

The
[Cmder](https://cmder.net/)
project is built upon ConEmu code, with enhancements from Clink.
Its
[Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) version
comes with a port to Windows of many Linux commands ready in the PATH.